# Making a level-scheme in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I usually make my level-schemes (nuclear physics ladder-type diagrams) in Mathematica. I am unable to access Mathematica where I am now, so would like a workaround using Gnuplot.

My datafile

```
1 -38.0820  2+
3 -38.0820

1 -36.43835 1+
3 -36.43835

1 -34.9315 3+
3 -34.9315

1 -31.3698 1+
3 -31.3698

1 -23.9041 0+
1 -23.9041
```

My input file above is called 'Li8'. The numbers in the first column (the 1,3) are dummy x-variables, values in column 2 are the energies (the numbers with four decimals), and then the "2+" etc. in the third column are the level-scheme labels

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the post itself states that this is not a question. (If you want to post a solution for your own problem, make a post that actually asks a question and then self-answer your own question.)

Comment: You can ask and answer your own question (and we like that), but you need to post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question to make it work. I've edited your Q to remove the answer you posted (but you can still find it in the edit history), you can post that as an answer yourself to retain credit/attribution properly.

Answer (score 1):

The code to make a level scheme in gnuplot could go something like this:

```
set terminal postscript
set output "Lithium-ls.ps"
set xrange [-1:5]
set yrange [-40:-24]
set ylabel "Energy [MeV]" font "arial, 24" rotate by 90
unset xtics
unset key
plot 'Li8' using 1:2 with lines lw 4, '' using 1:2:3 with labels offset 1,1 font "arial, 20"
```

This produces a pretty nice output
[Li8 levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Doj.png)